# a theorem in Shiryaev's probability Page 516

Tags: probability

I do not follow how to get the inequality of (5):

let $\tau^n_a=min(\tau_a,n) $

$\sup_{n} EX^+_{\tau_a^n} \le a+E[X^+_{\tau_a} I\{\tau_a \lt \infty\}]$

where, X is a submartingale, and  $X\in \mathbf C^+,$

which means $E[(\Delta X_{\tau_a})^+ I(\tau_a \lt a)] \lt \infty$, for every $a \gt 0$

Comment: Put dollars around your equation for it to display properly. The math formatting tutorial: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/166535

Comment: Could you please give what $a$ is in this context? Is $\tau _a$ the stopping time associated with $X_n$ crossing $a$? I'm sorry, it's just that I don't know where my copy of the book is at this precise moment.

Comment: Also, it would be best to say what $X_n$ is as well. Is it a martingale, a Markov chain, or maybe something else?